# Vertical align content of td with rowspan on tbody y-scrolling

Tags: html, css, scroll, html-table, vertical-alignment

Hi I am running into a problem with vertical aligning of a text in td elements with large rowspan.

```
vertical-align: top
```

works fine until the tbody is scrolled. On scrolling, the text of such cells is scrolled out.
Given that:

```
<table>
<tbody style="height: 100px; overflow-y: auto; display: block; width: 100%;">
......
<tr>
    <td rowspan="3">Row Span Cell</td>
    <td>normal cell 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>normal cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>normal cell 3</td>
</tr>
.......
</tbody>
</table>
```

How to avoid "Row Span Cell" disappearing until at least one "normal cell X" is visible (not scrolled out)? Note, it should be so only on tbody scrolling, not on all the page scrolling.

Comment: Could you please provide a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Here it is https://jsfiddle.net/eotc0haw/ if you scroll it the text in rowspanned cells is scrolled out but I would like it to stay on the top untill the entire cell is scrolled out

Comment: It's kind of difficult to know exactly what you're asking.. Do you mean you would like the text of the larger cell to remain at the top whilst scrolling through the smaller-sized cells?

Comment: Hi @CallanHeard, yes I want the text in a spanned cell stay visible until at least one not spanned cell on the same row is visible. In other words, as I said I want the text in spanned cell stays visible until the cell is scrolled out entirely. What would be also acceptable is that the text in the spanned cell be verically centered between the highest visible and the lowest visible points of that cell but I think it is more difficult to achive.

Comment: Hmm these effects will probably involve some JavaScript/jQuery, however if by the second one you mean simply vertically align the text to the middle of the cell, this can be done by simply removing the `vertical-align: top;` style: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eotc0haw/2/). I know this isn't exactly what you are after but it is much simpler to achieve!

Comment: Yes vertical-align: middle works the same way as top, that is the text is centered on the entire cell height not on the visible cell height as I want to. Any ideas? JS is welcome also!!!!

Comment: @DimD did u get it solved?